# update state in database when user clicks link php

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I am trying to make my php website update mysql database depending on which (one of two) link the user clicks, however, I either get both links in the database or just the same one. I am using an if statement since i am trying to differentiate between the links clicked.

I've tried using `$_GET['state']`, `$_REQUEST['state']`, rearranging my code, or using 2 if statements instead of 1 else if statement, but still no help. (`curr_stat` is my table), here is my code:

```
<?php
//if links are clicked, will write to database the status

$connect_error= 'Sorry, we are experiencing connection problems.';
$db_name = "database name";
$connection = @mysql_connect("some host", "some username","password") or die($connect_error);
$db3 = @mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection) or die($connect_error);

//if statement

$unlock = '<a href="doorlock.php?state=1">UNLOCK &nbsp;</a>&nbsp;';
echo $unlock;

$lock = '<a href="doorlock.php?state=0">LOCK</a>';
echo $lock;

if ($_GET['state'] == 1){
    $one = 1;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO curr_stat(status) VALUES($one)");
}
elseif ($_GET['state'] == 0){
    $zero = 0;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO curr_stat(status) VALUES($zero)");
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm not getting the exact problem. If you do it this way you would add a new row into your curr_stat table independent of the user who clicks. So if two user open the site and click a link you would have two entrys in your database. What is the sense of this?

Comment: Step 1: show html page with links.

Step 2: user click the link.

Step 3: PHP noticed the click and record it.

Please try to understand the steps and modify your code to fix your issue.

Comment: @dasKeks the purpose of adding a new row to curr_stat is to have a history of those clicked links because this website is for an electronic door lock. creating new rows, saving the "history" serves as an activity log for all users who have access, to see all the past lock states and therefore be able to see if their home is locked or not.

Answer (score 0):

You got one issue with your if statement:

If the get variable `state` is not defined the condition `($_GET['state'] == 0)` will return true.

So if you open the site without any parameters a new row for the status 0 is inserted.

This is why you either geht both 0 and 1 or two times the 0.

Instead you should test for a value not equal zero.

```
$unlock = '<a href="doorlock.php?state=1">UNLOCK &nbsp;</a>&nbsp;';
echo $unlock;

$lock = '<a href="doorlock.php?state=-1">LOCK</a>';
echo $lock;

if ($_GET['state'] == 1){
    $one = 1;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO curr_stat(status) VALUES($one)");
}
elseif ($_GET['state'] == -1){
    $zero = 0;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO curr_stat(status) VALUES($zero)");
}
?>
```

Comment: i'm still new to php, im not sure how to define it. i thought it was ok to use it since it is in doorlock.php?state=1 / 0.

Comment: I got it to work, using different method.  Thank you, regardless! will post answer soon!

Answer (score 0):

i got it to work!  I ended up trying something different.  I have an html file which also saves the status, one single integer, either 1 or 0, changes depending on which link is clicked, (doorlock.php?state=0, which is locked).  I used a function to open up that file, and read the data within the file.  I saved that data, and had an if statement to write to the database.  Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    //if links are clicked, will write to database the status

    $connect_error= 'Sorry, we are experiencing connection problems.';
    $db_name = "database name";
    $connection = @mysql_connect("some host", "some username","password") or         die($connect_error);
    $db = @mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection) or die($connect_error);

    //displays links
$unlock = '<a href="doorlock.php?state=1">UNLOCK &nbsp;</a>&nbsp;';
    echo $unlock;

    $lock = '<a href="doorlock.php?state=0">LOCK</a>';
    echo $lock;

//opens Lockstate.html file,and reads the data stored there
$file = "Lockstate.html";
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
$data = fread($fh, 1);
fclose($fh);
$state = $data;

//if statement to know what to write to database depending on the new status
// & displays it on the page after being clicked
if($data == 1){
    echo 'Door is now unlocked.';
    $one = 1;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO curr_stat(status) VALUES($one)");
}
if ($data == 0){
    echo 'Door is now locked.';
    $zero = 0; 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO curr_stat(status) VALUES($zero)");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<td> <?PHP  echo "<a href='action.php?kisi=$id'  onclick='return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: &#39;iframe&#39; } )'>$ad $soyad</a>";?></td>`

when the link is clicked another user can not click (database can not change)